# how to lock config file in shell script so that no one updates once the script starts running

Tags: linux, shell, locking, flock

I have a configuration file that has all the environment variables present. So this config file is used in my shell script. My shell script takes lots of time for it to be executed, and it is being run on a VM. I don't want my config file to get updated meanwhile. I need to lock-down all the variables present in the config file so that no one updates it. once the shell script finishes it can unlock the config file

Comment: If have a control over over process which can possibly modify the file, then it's easy to achieve with flock, but you need to put flock in each such process. If you need to restrict access from arbitrary process, then in general it's impossible or very hard, look for mandatory file locking: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt

Comment: What other processes access the config file? Are all those processes under your control such that you can modify their implementation to use [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock)?

Comment: actually the environment variable which I am talking about is $date. this is present in the config file. it should lock $(date) till my script finishes executing and unlock it once it is done

Comment: Then it's not clear what you are asking. Just save the value in a variable and use that variable as long as you like. It won't change unless you change it. You really need to make your question much clearer.

Comment: @AbhishekDiwate : Maybe this is a sign of a badly designed script. There should be no need for the script to re-read the config files, so after that file has been processed the first time, there is no harm if someone is editing it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to make your file immutable. This is done with command:

```
chattr +i <filename>
```

if you want to remove the flag use command

```
chattr -i <filename>
```